# Found a String in a Set of Integer after casting

Tags: java

Today I noticed this strange behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> mySetA = get(Arrays.asList("1"));
    test(mySetA);
}

private static <T> Set<T> get(Object b) {
    Set<T> a = new HashSet<T>(cast(b));
    return a;
}

public static <T> T cast(Object object) {
    return (T) object;
}

private static void test(Set<Integer> test) {
    test.stream().forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
}
```

When I use the debugger to look at the content of mySetA, I see that it contains a String "1", even though mySetA is supposed to be a Set of Integer.
When I run the following code I get the exception:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Could anyone explain the reason why this might be happening?

To be clearer: I'm not looking for a "fix". I want to understand why my code is compiling but something like this isn't:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> mySetA = get(Arrays.asList("1"));
    test(mySetA);
}

private static <T> Set<T> get(Object b) {
    Set<T> a = new HashSet<T>((T) b);
    return a;
}

private static void test(Set<Integer> test) {
    test.stream().forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You gave it a string and then carefully lied to the type system to get it to compile. What makes you think `"1"` is an integer in the first place? You're casting through `Object` which means you're basically circumventing the type checker entirely.

Comment: Change to Set<Integer> mySetA = get(Arrays.asList(1));

Comment: Well, that's my issue, "1" isn't an integer, and I don't understand why this is compiling. Why would something like this compile? I am not looking for a "fix" but for an explanation on why this is compiling.

Comment: Same reason `new HashSet<T>(cast(b), cast("b"))` compiles. Or `((Object)null).toString()`. Or `new ArrayList<>().get(0)`. Casting is one of countless ways to trick the runtime into throwing an exception.

Comment: Two word answer: [**Type Erasure**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Type erasure explains why the error message isn't something like "List<String> cannot be cast to Collection<Integer>". I'm not sure that was the question though.

Comment: *I want to understand why my code is compiling but something like this isn't*... They're totally different. The first is casting to `Collection<? extends T>`. The second is casting to `T`, which the constructor isn't asking for.

Comment: @shmosel A `List<String>` is being added to a `Set<Object>` and the *bridge method* which performs the cast blows up when OP attempts to access it as a `Set<Integer>` (which happens because of the way generics were added to the language). Perhaps we should mention that you can't cast a `String` to an `Integer` and expect it to work at runtime; so this shouldn't really be a surprise.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Pretty sure it's blowing up when the lambda is invoked. But what's your point?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so what you're saying is that I can cast a Set<String> to a Set<Integer> without raising any runtime error, but once i try to access the content of the set I get an error?

Comment: @shmosel Well, OP said *When I use the debugger to look at the content of mySetA, I see that it contains a String "1", even though mySetA is supposed to be a Set of Integer* And the reason that can happen is because after type erasure it's a `Set<Object>`.

Comment: @Maxime Exactly. But only if you ignore the warning in the `cast()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> mySetA = get(Arrays.asList("1"));
    // test(mySetA);
}

private static <T> Set<T> get(Object b) {
    Set<T> a = new HashSet<T>(cast(b));
    return a;
}

public static <T> T cast(Object object) {
    return (T) object;
}
```

Let's cut out the middle man and just show the *types* you're working with. First, you make a list of strings. That's `List<String>`. Then you cast that to `Object` when you pass it to `get`. You take that `Object` (which is actually a list of strings) and cast to `Collection<Integer>` for the `HashSet` constructor. So you're taking a `List<String>` and casting *through* `Object`. We could do this for any two types in the entire Java language. Give me any two classes, say `Foo` and `Bar`. I could do

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Object b = (Object)a;
Bar c = (Bar)b;
```

The compiler wouldn't give it a second thought: no errors. At runtime, this will obviously fail, but that's simply because we did an unsafe cast. You're doing the same thing; you're just hiding it behind several helper functions. In general, casting to `Object` is a code smell, and doing an unchecked cast *away* from `Object` is definitely a red flag.

Would it be nice if Java didn't let us do unsafe casts without checking? Yes, it would be. But that's not the reality.

Comment: In your example, as you said, you're getting an error at runtime when casting b to Bar and assigning it to c. In my case, what's strange is that I'm only getting a runtime error when I call test(), and i'm actually able to have a Set<Integer> filled with strings.

Comment: Check out the type erasure link in one of the comments. The JVM doesn't check whether generic typecasts work at runtime because the JVM doesn't know about generics. As far as it's concerned, you're just casting a `Set` to a `Set`, which is fine.